# Индекс цифры в числе

Tags: python

нужно найти порядковый номер цифры в числе.

```
q = 123421434  #для примера
k=int(input())
print(int(q[k]))
```

После этого команда больше не работает,и все действия, происходящие после не учитываются. Хотелось бы узнать, почему так. Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 3):

потому что у вас `q` это число, а к числу мы не можем обращаться по индексу. Чтобы обратится по индексу его надо перевести в строку

```
q = "123421434"
k=int(input())
print(int(q[k]))
```

Comment: Можно еще добавить, что `q[k]` вызывает ошибку `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` :) Поэтому странно, что у автора ничего не происходит в коде, мб где-то try/except находится, который ловит исключение, но не выводит